# I need an adjective for “choosing the hard way”

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for an adjective which conveys that a decision is challenging and pushing yourself instead of taking an easier option.

For example:

> The young choir and orchestra performed Jesus Christ Superstar which was a very ____________ choice as it is extremely complex.

So it kind of means *brave.*

Comment: A look for synonyms of 'brave' (which itself works well) would turn up 'plucky', which is conversationally fine. All brave etc acts are choices.

Answer (score 4):

You could say that it was an **[ambitious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ambitious)** choice.

> 1.1 (of a plan or piece of work) intended to satisfy high aspirations and therefore difficult to achieve:
>   *‘an ambitious enterprise’*

(Oxford)

The entry lists these synonyms: *difficult, exacting, demanding, formidable, challenging, hard, arduous, onerous, tough, stiff, strenuous*

But I don't think any of these fit the  bill better than *ambitious*.

Comment: Fitting answer. (Challenging would have been my first choice.)

Comment: I like 'ambitious', but in this case, I think 'challenging' is slightly better. To me, the former suggests its about the level of the target - the JCS score is difficult, but perhaps these kids are just that good. Whereas the latter suggests that the JCS score is sufficiently difficult that is going to really test these kids. To me, a close third place is 'demanding'.

Comment: @CJM: Good point. Your inferences sound right to me too. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Nah... the differences between your answers is subjective. I've offered my take, but the OP might differ. Either way, your post offers a number of suitable suggestions for any reader to choose from - me claiming one as my own isn't really going to contribute much.:)

Answer (score 1):

Excuse the simplicity but *a [daring](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daring) choice*, perhaps.

> : venturesomely bold in action or
>    thought
>   OD: (of a person or action) adventurous or
>   audaciously bold

Also consider the synonyms- audacious, bold, gutsy....